# How do I split a string at the third occurrence of the character? [android]

Tags: java, android, string, rss

I have two separate strings that are going to be fetched from an RSS Feed. These are my getLink() values.

String one would be like: http://www.example.in/something/source.rss

String two would be like: http://www.example.com/somthing/source2.rss

I only want to display on my ListView:

> www.example.in
>
> www.example.com

So, how do I split the string so that it ends at the third occurrence of "/" ?

Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code.

```
String kek = "http://www.example.com/somthing/source2.rss";
String ohh = kek.substring(7, kek.length());
String my = ohh.substring(0, ohh.indexOf("/"));
Log.e("test", my);
```

Here output will be

> www.example.com

**Update**

efficient way to do it

```
String u = "http://www.example.com/somthing/source2.rss";
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(u);
    String host = url.getHost();
    Log.e("test", host);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: in that code we get sub-string from main string. first we removed "http://" and then removed string String occurring after first index of "/".

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is OK but not efficient, because is complication the search criteria...

Use the URL class from java.net and what you need is actually the host....

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
       String a = "http://www.example.in/something/source.rss";
       String b = "http://www.example.com/somthing/source2.rss";
       System.out.println("host = " + new URL(a).getHost());
       System.out.println("host = " + new URL(b).getHost());
}
```

the output will be:

> host = www.example.in
>
> host = www.example.com

Comment: Creating a new URL object is actually much less efficient

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and will also work

```
    String str="http://www.example.in/something/source.rss";
    int init=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        init=str.indexOf("/",init+1);
    }
    System.out.println(str.substring(0,init));
```